# What does this number means in user details?

Tags: discussion, users

[image]
What does this circled number means in  Movies and TV beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is your [Reputation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) score on Movies and TV. I think From the screenshot, that is your monthly score, i.e. the reputation you have accrued in May.

Reputation is a (or even the) core concept on Stackexchange, you earn it by being recognized for your contributions by other users and you gain privileges from it. Look at the link above and read about it in the FAQ.

Comment: i know aboout reputaion basic but i didnot know previously that the number shown here are the monthly reputaion total. Thanx for the help

Comment: Glad to help. You can click on links to give you weekly, monthly or year-to-date totals, as well as all.